# Constructing a vector consisting of nonnegative entries

Tags: co.combinatorics, puzzle

Consider constructing a vector $v=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ consisting of nonnegative integers such that $a_1=1$ and, if $a_j$'s are nonzero, then $a_j\equiv a_{n-j+2}+j-1 \pmod m\ \forall 1<j\le\frac{n}{2}$, where $m$ is the number of nonzero entries; with the additional constraint that all nonzero $a_i$'s are distinct modulo $m$. Note that  the number $m$ itself appears once as a nonzero number satisfying the above congruence.

Is it always possible to construct such a vector? I think this should be possible if $m$ is odd. For example, $(1,4,2,5,3)$ and $(1,4,2,0,0,5,3)$ are such vectors. It is easy to construct if the first  entries (within $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$) of the vector are consecutive. But, in other cases, it is not clear as to how to proceed with the construction. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Your two examples are nonnegative, have $a_1=1$, and have distinct nonzero entries, but the mod condition fails for both.

Comment: @RobPratt thanks! edited. see now.

Comment: Still not right. For $j=2$, $4\not\equiv 5+2-1 \pmod 5$.

Comment: @RobPratt no, we do have $4\equiv 3+2-1 \pmod 5$. In fact you misread $a_{n-j+1}$ for $n$

Comment: For the first example, $n=5$, and $j=2$ yields $a_{n-j+1}=a_{5-2+1}=a_4=5\not= 3$.

Comment: @RobPratt sorry, again edited hope its correct now.

Comment: Your second example fails for $j=6$ because $5\not\equiv 2+6-1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: @RobPratt well observed,  edited again now. Actually the condition is derived from the condition of being able to obtain a symmetric anti-circulant matrix by shifting the vector $v$.

Comment: What is given? Both $n$ and $m$?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev yes, suppose I specify any $n$ and $m$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such construction is always possible.

Consider two sets of pairs of values:
$$\big\{ (2+t,m-t)\quad :\quad t=0\,..\,\lfloor\frac{m-1}{4}\rfloor-1\big\},$$
where differences of elements modulo $m$ are: $2,4,\dots,2\cdot\lfloor\frac{m-1}{4}\rfloor$, and
$$\big\{ (\lfloor\frac{m+1}{2}\rfloor+t+1,\lfloor\frac{m+1}{2}\rfloor-t)\quad :\quad t=0\,..\,\lfloor\frac{m+1}{4}\rfloor-1\big\},$$
where differences of elements modulo $m$ are: $1, 3, \dots, 2\cdot\lfloor\frac{m+1}{4}\rfloor-1.$ Together they give all differences from $1$ to $\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor$.

Notice that all elements forming pairs in these sets are $\ne0,1$ and are distinct modulo $m$.

Therefore, it's enough to assign the values from these sets to the corresponding pairs $(a_j,a_{n+2-j})$, giving $2\cdot\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor$ nonzero $a_j$'s. If $m$ is even we need to assign one more yet unassigned nonzero value (which is  $\lfloor\frac{3m}{4}\rfloor+1$) to any of yet unassigned $a_j$ with $j>\frac{n}2$. The other unassigned $a_j$ are set to zero.

---

**ADDED.** Here is a [SageMath code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtkc-KwyAQxu99ioFS0E6k1ZYeAnmSEIJUswirIdb2suy7r_8gHtbD4Hz85ptxVHqB5-pewb-fYZbEdZb2B4hHf7SbFQwwEoGhsyxQWFYPAYwDL92XJsQyTi-XO51yxRZhYjFJIgurUtVhw4C82_71wNYjh1xznc7kWzuSTSimaxmJ0gKNfS-mSGagSrxqhdwdZXV0JYvXKPCcpHnMPk_qE1uUHRTYIE-4Gs2UCgGOIOcfg-K3gRwKRqJG2Q7z5k1mAXsSw3BtnVnpVkrI7WzTJgDrZDl4Hd7egYzJof0o_ug4p38tnm9E&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) implementing the above construction. There is a sample call `construct_a(16,11)`, which constructs vector $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ for parameters $n=16$ and $m=11$.

Comment: great! how did you get such an idea?

Comment: @vidyarthi: a lot of drawing on a piece of paper ;)

Comment: you mean you drew paths of odd and even order between the numbers $a_j$ and $a_{n-j+2}$?

Comment: @vidyarthi: I drew matchings between residues modulo $m$ giving differences $1,2,\dots$

Comment: ok, you are actually a computational biologist, is number theory and combinatorics your hobby?

Comment: @vidyarthi: sort of ;)

Comment: Actually, I have another problem now. My problem requirements also state that the numbers in the individual pairs $(a_j,a_{n+2-j})$ must not be equivalent to $(j,n+2-j)$ modulo $r$. Now, is that also possible? By the above construction, this would occur at the point when $j\equiv1\pmod r$. So how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: I meant $r$ to be $m$ in my previous comment

Comment: I do not quite follow. The difference in $(j,n+2-j)$ is $2j-n-2$. If it's assigned to $(a_j,a_{n+2-j})$, the the difference is congruent to $j-1$ modulo $m$, implying $j\equiv n+1\pmod m$. Why you say $j\equiv 1\pmod m$?

Comment: I wanted the difference between $a_j$ and $a_{n+2-j}$ in the OP to be $j-1\pmod m$. Using your rule, I equate this to either $2+2t$(even difference) or $2t+1$(odd difference), obtaining $t=\frac{j-3}{2}$ and $t=\frac{j-2}{2}$ respectively. This means when $j\equiv1\pmod m$, and $j$ is odd, we would obtain $a_j=2+t= 2+\frac{j-3}{2}\equiv j\pmod m$. But, I do not want $a_j$ to be conguent to $j$. Is my method of equating $2+2t$ and $2t+1$ with $j-1$ wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is true that $j\equiv n+1\pmod m$. But, if I were to suppose that $m| n$, then I would get by conclusion. Anyways, the main thing is to ensure that the numbers $a_j$ and $a_{n+2-j}$ are not congruent to $j$ and $n+2-j$ respectively, Can this be done. Assume that $m$ divides $n$

Comment: Assume $m|n$. There are no $j\equiv 1\pmod m$ in the interval $[2,n/2]$ if $m\geq n/2$. So, the additional restriction playa role only when $m\leq n/3$. However, in this case we can simply assign all nonzero values to $a_j$'s with $j>n/2$.

Comment: sorry, I did not get your second part. Could you illustrate the part when $m\le\frac{n}{3}$. And what about the part $\frac{n}{3}<m<\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: For $m\leq n/3$, simply set $a_{n/2+k}=k$ for $k=1..m$, and all other $a_j$ to 0. If $n/3<m<n/2$, then $m$ cannot divide $n$.

Comment: sorry, again a confusion. For $m\le\frac{n}{3}$, suppose $a_{\frac{n}{2}+3}=3$. Then, since we have $a_{\frac{n}{2}-1}=0$, therefore the difference is $-3=m-3\pmod m$.So how is the difference in this case $j-1=\frac{n}{2}-2\pmod m$? And, by the way, can I not have nonzero entries before $a_{\frac{n}{2}}$?

Comment: I do not quite follow again. According to your original question, the congruence $a_j\equiv a_{n+2-j}+j-1\pmod m$ is required only for nonzero $a_j$. In the above example, for $j=n/2-1$ we have $a_j=0$, and so the congruence may not hold.

Comment: oh yes thanks, i forgot about that. so you have completely answered the modified problem. only last thing is whether i could have nonzero entries before $a_{\frac{n}{2}}$.

Comment: How many nonzero entries you want before $a_{n/2}$? When $m\leq n/3$, it's unavoidable that some of these entries will be zero.

Comment: say, by symmetry that $\frac{n}{6}$ entries are nonzero before $a_{n/2}$

Comment: Then simply assign pairs of values as in my answer, but if such assignment violates your additional restriction, then re-assign both values to any available $a_j$ with $j>n/2$.

Comment: again a problem, the differences in the first pair $(2+t,m-t)$ are always odd if $m$ is odd. So, how can you ensure all the dfferences? Although the pairs give distinct entries, but the proof you give is not clear.

Comment: We consider differences modulo $m$. So, here it does not matter if $m$ is even or odd - in either case we get $(2+t)-(m-t)\equiv 2+2t\pmod m$.

Comment: but take $t=2, m=17$ . Then $2+t=4,m-t=15$, and the difference is odd. The problem is that the difference is $2+2t-m$, which is less than (in magnitude) $m$, whence modulo does not keep the parity unaffected

Comment: The proof i think need not mention the parity of differences. Instead, only the distinctness of the numbers in both the pairs would do to prove that all the numbers from $2$ to $m$ are covered. But anyways, the answer is right and works well!

Comment: Sorry, again a problem. Suppose I want to construct a vector like $\{1,*, 0, *,*,*,0,*,0,0,0,0,0,*,0,*,*,*,0,*\}$, where $*$ denotes the nonnegative entries. The differences between nonnegatives in this case modulo $m=11$ in this case are $1, 3,4, 5, 7$. So isnt is asymmetric. What are the entries in this case?

Comment: @vidyarthi: This is a different problem from what you originally asked. Here is a solution obtained by brute-force: $$(1,11,0,8,7,9,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,4,3,5,0,10)$$

Comment: how is it a different problem? I think i asked the same problem. Anyways, is brute force the only way, or can we state the possibility from by a fixed algorithm; or, is it altogether unpredictable to construct such a vector

Comment: @vidyarthi: In your original problem, the positions of zeroes were not fixed. The one you just asked is more restrictive in that sense. I did not claim that brute-force is the only way - it's just the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: yes, the positions of zeros are not fixed, but once we put a nonzero entry before $n/2$th column, we automatically put another after $n/2$, so in that sense, the nonzero entries before $n/2$th column are the real variables. Yes, brute force is the natural thought, but whether it is always possible is my only question

Comment: @vidyarthi: Since it's a different problem, I'd recommend to accurately formulate it as a new question, which would be more suitable at https://math.stackexchange.com/ I may have another algorithm for your new problem, but I cannot explain it here.

Comment: done, its [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020443/construction-of-a-vector-consisting-of-entries-with-a-peculiar-pattern)

Comment: I do not see any difference from the question here, which I answered. In the comments you imposed additional restriction on positions of zeros - why didn't you mention this restriction in the new question?

Comment: Done some slight modification. By the way, I just want that whenever I put a nonzero number, I have a complementary nonzero number determined modulo $m$. We could put the zeros in the other places. Thus, in this sense, there is no condition of zeros as such. Could you explain your dilemma a bit more?

Comment: My answer gives you a construction that answers your original question here and the new question at MSE (since it's still a duplicate). I'm not sure what else you are asking in your questions -- it seems you have some additional restrictions in mind, which you do not state explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119592/discussion-between-max-alekseyev-and-vidyarthi).

Answer (score 0):

Computational experiments for $1 \le m \le n \le 20$ yield feasible solutions even if you impose the upper bound $a_j \le n$.  Here is an infinite family for $m \le \lceil n/2\rceil +1$:
$$(1,\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-m},2,3,4,\dots,m)$$

Here are the lexicographically smallest solutions for $n=m$:
\begin{matrix}
n & a\\
\hline
1& (1)\\
2& (1, 2)\\
3& (1, 2, 3)\\
4& (1, 3, 4, 2)\\
5& (1, 3, 4, 5, 2)\\ 
6& (1, 3, 6, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
7& (1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2)\\ 
8& (1, 3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
9& (1, 3, 6, 8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
10& (1, 3, 6, 10, 9, 8, 5, 7, 4, 2)\\ 
11& (1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
12& (1, 3, 6, 11, 9, 12, 10, 7, 5, 8, 4, 2)\\ 
13& (1, 3, 6, 8, 13, 12, 10, 11, 7, 9, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
14& (1, 3, 6, 10, 12, 14, 5, 11, 13, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2)\\ 
15& (1, 3, 6, 8, 14, 12, 15, 11, 13, 9, 7, 10, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
16& (1, 3, 6, 10, 12, 16, 15, 5, 13, 14, 9, 11, 8, 7, 4, 2)\\ 
17& (1, 3, 6, 8, 13, 15, 17, 14, 12, 16, 7, 11, 10, 9, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
18& (1, 3, 6, 8, 13, 16, 18, 17, 15, 14, 7, 10, 12, 11, 9, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
19& (1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 17, 19, 16, 18, 14, 15, 10, 9, 13, 12, 7, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
20& (1, 3, 6, 8, 13, 17, 20, 18, 15, 19, 16, 10, 7, 11, 14, 12, 9, 5, 4, 2)\\ 
\end{matrix}

Comment: thanks, but what about the general case? And even in the cases you have provided, what happens when I introduce zeroes in between the numbers ( thereby increasing $n$ keeping $m$ fixed) ?